# Completely disable Windows 8.1 SkyDrive integration

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I've used the group policy to disable SkyDrive as i'm behind a corporate firewall that blocks it. Despite this, and it being gone from explorer every time the PC boots I'm displayed this error. Any ideas?

[image: SkyDrive integration is crap]

Comment: try this: http://www.ghacks.net/2013/11/02/disable-skydrive-windows-8-1/

Comment: Already have, still getting the error.